# Several Filters in Cognito ListUsers

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to filter in my presignup lambda for a few params (in the same call) with Cognito ListUserRequest but it doesn't work.
Somebody knows a workaround without making several calls?
Thanks a lot!

```
 ListUsersRequest listUsersRequest = new ListUsersRequest();
 listUsersRequest.withUserPoolId(USER_POOL_ID);
 listUsersRequest.withFilter("username = \"" + USER_NAME + "\" and email = \"" + EMAIL + "\""");
```

Comment: It is not supported yet. Implement it by yourself. I guest just filter by username is enough.

Comment: Thanks! I have to valide other fields 'cause must be uniques, like email, phone or documentId.